# Best way to contribute?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow all !

I'm aware of that [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/10349/whats-the-best-way-to-contribute-back-stacks-and-packages/), I read the answer carefully and it provide a lot of very useful answers. But I'd like to have more information and ask some more stuff as I'm a total noob when it comes to contribute and everything.

I've been working on ROS in the last couple of month and I think it's a fantastic project. Even though I'm not sure my contributions would be "useful" I'd like at least to know how "it works" for if a day I found the courage to invest more of myself in it =).

- This question is the most important to me : What's the best way to know if a project would be useful for the community ? I know there is a ROS mailing list, a release list and this answer site. Which one should I go on to ask whether or not I should contribute my project ?
  For example, I, right now, created a package that is a small [ORK](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/) in C++ only made for fast testing of Object recognition pipeline. I did this because I needed something simpler than ORK to begin testing with. Now, I have no idea if there is a point in sharing that project or not and up to which point. Especially since ORK is there. That would be one question, **how to know when contributing is relevant** ?
- Is there some way and place to get help in doing so ? Meaning, I know how to set up a repo on github and edit a page on the wiki... Apart from that, it's really unclear. When should I [index](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation) it? How should I tell people? What is the normal "patern" to respect ? Can I get help and having someone taking me by the hand the first time :P ?

I may add some more question to this topic if they come to mind later.

Thanks a lot everyone !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165831/best-way-to-contribute-?/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my opinion to answer the most generic question: A project is useful if someone else could get some use out of it and it's buildable/documented/generic to that point. This is a very low requirement meaning: Someone could get it to work somehow. In other words: You're free to "officially" share everything that you think is useful. It would be helpful to announce if the state is e.g. experimental, though.

Here is the usual way up:

1. Announce on ros-users with a repository, e.g. github. You can do this for almost any project.
2. Index it. Basically it will now show up in the wiki, can be easily found and documented. I would say that the project should be somewhat usable for this step, i.e. at least basically working. Should also have a proper name that doesn't collide with anything.
3. Release it. Will be build into debians on the farm and available for apt-get. For this to work it should conform to some ROS standards, be buildable out of the box, etc. ros-release is the mailing list to get help here.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-16**:
Thanks, it's a really useful answer !